# Using Weka on Images

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am new to Weka, and from the examples on how to use it, I have only seen text problems. Can I use images in Weka with the machine learning classifiers?

Answer (score 8):

You can directly do **pixel classification** using the [`Trainable Weka Segmentation`](http://fiji.sc/Trainable_Weka_Segmentation) plugin (former Advanced Weka Segmentation plugin) from `Fiji/ImageJ`.

The plugin is designed for **segmentation via interactive learning**. This means the user is expected to select a set of features (edge detectors, texture filters, etc.), choose the number of classes (by default there are 2) and interactively draw (with the ROI tools) samples of all classes. After training the classifier based on those samples, the whole image pixels will be classified and the segmentation result will be displayed overlaying the original image. The idea is to repeat this process (drawing + training) until obtaining a satisfying segmentation.

The plugin provides as well a set of tools to save/load the samples in [`ARFF format`](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) and save/load the classifier in .model format, so it's completely compatible with the latest version of WEKA.

If what you want to do is **image classification**, you might be able to reuse some of the plugin's methods as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use open source Image processing application such as [`ImageJ`](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/) and [`Fiji`](http://fiji.sc/) to extract features from your image and use it in `Weka`

Fiji has a plugin called [Advanced Weka Segmentation](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Advanced_Weka_Segmentation) which should be very useful in applying Weka classifiers to Image

Answer (score 2):

Weka machine learning classifiers works with numerical and categorical features. Before using weka with images, you need to [extract features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) from your images. 
According to your needs, simple features like average, maximum, mean may be enough. Or you may need to use some other algorithms for your images.

Below wikipedia feature extraction algorithms.

Low-level

- Edge detection
- Corner detection
- Blob detection
- Ridge detection
- Scale-invariant feature transform

I suggest reading a optical character recognition survey to understand how they are used. OCR is pretty simple example for you to use. Standard data sets and algorithms exists for OCR. Therefore it is very instructive to learn about it.